# C# logic question

Tags: c#, boolean-logic

I have those boolean values:

```
bool test = false && true || true; // true
bool test1 = false && (true || true); // false
```

Now, can anybody explain why this is? Shouldnt those be the same?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The && operator has [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323.aspx) over || meaning that your first expression is equivalent to:

```
bool test = (false && true) || true;
```

which gives:

```
bool test = false || true;
```

which gives:

```
bool test = true;
```

In the second case you are explicitly grouping the operands:

```
bool test1 = false && (true || true);
```

which gives:

```
bool test1 = false && true;
```

which gives:

```
bool test1 = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

in test you have `false && true`, which is false and then you have `false || true` which is `true`.
In the second case you evaluate `(true || true)` at first => `true` and then `false && true` which is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` is evaluated first in your first expression - meaning you end up with the result of `false || true`, rather than `false && true` in the second expression.

Answer (score 0):

The first evaluates `false && true` first (`false`) and then the result with `|| true`, which gives `true`.

The second evaluates the value in the parenthesis first so `true || true` and then the result with `&& false`, which gives `false`

Answer (score 0):

In your first example false && true is evaluated first and it evaluated as false. Then false OR true is of course evaluated to true.

In your second, because of the () true OR true is evaluated first to true, then true && false is evaluated to false.

So it makes perfectly sense.

Answer (score 0):

First one:

```
False and True or True
```

One condition satisfied, So its return true

Second one:

```
False and (True or True) = False and True
```

one condition failed, So its return false

Answer (score 0):

`bool test = false && true || true; // true`

This first is true because the statement is testing whether the it is true or false.

`bool test1 = false && (true || true); // false`

The second one if false because the statement is testing whether it is true and false.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one && has precedence over || because you have not grouped explicitly.

In the second one, (...) lead to || being evaluated first.

Thus the differing results.

Answer (score 0):

The order of precedence flows in the following order

1. ()
2. &&
3. ||

Hence in first case `&&` takes over `||` and insecond case `()` takes over `&&`